# What are some good distractions for an infant?

Tags: infant, behavior, activities

My 4 month old is nearly able to sit up on his own and has gotten rather bored with activity mats, swings, and hanging toys. The only things of his he still likes, are a bit too advanced to hold his interest long; he enjoys his stacking cups and blocks, but lacks enough coordination to not get frustrated. He only seems to be happy if we hold him constantly and wants us to keep him in a standing position most of the time.

Do any of you know of any good toys that could keep him entertained so my wife and I could get a bit of a break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the activity mat with an activity walker. Even though he doesn't walk yet, the upright orientation is new to him and encourages sitting up so he can reach the upper parts. Or lay it flat on the floor to begin with.

[image: example]
Amazon: [search for baby walker](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_11?url=search-alias=baby-products&field-keywords=baby%20walker&x=0&y=0&sprefix=baby%20walker)

Comment: That's a really neat toy. I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: My 10 month old has something very similar.  Bought if for him a several months ago.  Initially he was happy just sitting and pressing the buttons, and slowly but surely his progressed to pushing it around.  Excellent toy.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, it sounds like your baby is advanced!  If he's good at holding his head up, he might enjoy a jumper (either free-standing, or one that attaches to a door frame).  My daughter got to that "hold me up all the time" stage a month ago or so, and she *loves* her jumper.

Answer (score 1):

My kids (now 12 and 10) loved the ExerSaucer!

It allows the child to stand up and has a swiveling seat that allows 360 degree movement with different activities around the toy such as light ups, music, and teething toys. This particular version has 3 stages:

-A play mat for up to 4 months (sounds like you are past this use)

-Traditional ExerSaucer for 4 months until walking

-Activity table once walking

There are tons of different versions available.

[image: ExerSaucer]

Answer (score 1):

My son was captivated by lights, and especially lights that 1) are in a circle or formation he can gaze at , and 2) ones that blink or can be turned on or off.  I found colored and blinking christmas type lights and he loved them for hours.  He was also attracted to shiny metallic objects and prisms and pieces of smooth glass.

(I was sort of against all the plastic textures in his life.)